# Auto enable YouTube captions when available

Tags: youtube, subtitles

Is it possible to automatically enable builtin captions for YouTube videos?

I want it only when there are real subtitles, not when there's only auto-translation.

Answer (score 1):

did you try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzcuEa-An8c)?

[image]

settings > playback > 3rd checkbox unchecked

Comment: Yes, those are the settings I have